# How to solve gmail spam filter issue

Tags: gmail, spam

We have a problem when sending emails to "gmail.com" domain. All of our emails end up in spam folder.

We do not send spam or bulk emails, so I would like to know is there a way to solve this issue.

I have browsed some topics and it appears we are not blacklisted, but the problem is in spam filtering.

Really don't know what do do next

Comment: How's your SPF check going? Send a mail to a GMail account, then look at the unfiltered version (it's under "View original"). Look at what SPF said, maybe you have an MX issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real solution. The best things you can do for now is to enable both SPF and DKIM for your domain/mail server, but google's filter is still pretty strict.

Comment: Oh, and be sure that the DKIM key is over 1024b in size. Google is getting strict even about keys size!